# Missing destination file operand

Tags: ubuntu, cp

I am beginner as far as Linux is concerned and therfore ran into trouble with the following command.

```
$ cp VRP/share/ViennaRNA/bin/*.
```

The error I got is as follows:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after 'VRP/share/ViennaRNA/bin/*.'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Could you describe your intention with the copy command? What files do you want to copy where?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error because `cp` is [expecting two operands](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) and you are only supplying one.

If you are trying to copy everything from `VRP/share/ViennaRNA/bin/*` to your current location (as indicated by `.`) then you're simply missing a space between your `*` and `.`.

Try this:

```
$ cp VRP/share/ViennaRNA/bin/* .
```

Note that this will skip directories. If you want that, use the `-r` flag.

Comment: It will also skip dotfiles (aka "hidden" files: files whose name starts with a period) unless you tell your shell otherwise. In bash, you can set `dotglob` to include dotfiles in the match: `shopt -s dotglob`.